# jQuery UJS event binding

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How does jQuery UJS know when document is ready and starts attaching events to selected elements?

In my case it seems to start binding too soon (document not loaded).

Comment: Please provide more context and some code, it's impossible to answer on question like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery_ujs` uses delegation to handle events (as of 3.2, Rails 4 may use `.on`):

```
 $(document).delegate(...)
```

so there is no binding to an element. All events are bound to `document` and filtered by selectors.

Comment: Does this mean that delegate(...) can be called on document which is not ready yet?

Comment: The object `document` is existing all the time, even if the DOM stucture in it is not yet complete. So yes, you can bind to it before the whole page is loaded. Because `delegate` waits for events to bubble up the DOM tree, it can handle events for elements that didn't exist when `delegate` was executed. That's what the jQuery docu means with `Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future`